# BODMAS, definition of "orders"

Tags: arithmetic

I've struggled to find in google the exact definition of the word "orders" as used in bodmas's second operation. I know what it means (powers, indeces etc.) but I'm looking for the proper mathematical definition and how I could use it in a sentence. Can I say for example "3 raised to the order 2"?

Edit to add: I'm referring to the "orders" in the mnemonic as in brackets, orders, division etc. where orders means powers. Not about order in "order of operations".

Comment: [Order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Definition) means the sequence : first, second,... to be followed performing the arithmetical operations.

Comment: The word "order" is used in a variety of ways in mathematics. Your "BODMAS" is a made-up word, a mnemonic to help one remember the usual *precedence" of operations in arithmetic expressions.

Comment: I'm asking about the use of orders as in brackets, orders, division, multiplication etc. not as in order of operations.

Comment: The word order is mainly used in mathematics for a structure whose definition is well known. It is very useful that synonyms are not used in mathematics but nevertheless it is actually used in particular for "order of growth of a function", "differential equations of such order" "square matrices of order n" and some others I suppose. But I have never heard "" 3 raised to the order 2 "and would ensure that such an expression should be avoided.

Comment: Another common acronym for this is [PEMDAS](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/orderops.htm), where in place of "orders" we have the *exponents* operation.

Comment: Old use; see [Order (degree)](http://jeff560.tripod.com/o.html).

Comment: Mauro, that is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"BODMAS" may well be taught before students have even encountered the notion of exponentiation. In that context it really should be "BDMAS"*, but of course this is not readily pronounceable so an "O" was added. The explanation I was given at school was that this stood for "of" (i.e. the other things can be inside the brackets), which doesn't really mean anything. I suspect "order" was just a post-hoc attempt to make this include exponentiation without changing the acronym; it's not used with that meaning elsewhere in mathematics.

*or really "$\mathrm{B}^\mbox{D}_\mbox{M}{}^\mbox{A}_\mbox{S}$" since D/M (mostly) have equal precedence, as do A/S, but that's even harder to say.

Comment: It's given as BODMAS in GCSE textbooks with O to mean orders.

Comment: @Eva It is now, but I suspect that is relatively recent and the word was chosen to fit in with a pre-existing acronym.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mathematical definition of orders. It's used here as a collective lay term and not as a proper mathematical one.

Comment: Can I say "3 raised to the order 2"?

Comment: No. You say it as  "3 raised to the second power", "3 raised to the power of 2", "the second power of 3", "3 squared".